# Astra h, gear box overflow plug location

Tags: automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid, astra, holden, fluid-level

I have Holden Astra 2008 wagon. Engine z18-xer (1.8 litres) with 4 steps automatical transmission (AF17). I need to replace transmission fluid. Please help me find an overflow plug, (it is also called "level plug" or "level check hole" or "fluid checking bolt").

The same Astra model was made under the Brand Opel and Vauxhall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://workshop-manuals.com/vauxhall/astra-h/k__clutch_and_transmission/automatic_transmission_front_wheel_drive/automatic_transmission_af_13/17/14/20/22/30/repair_instructions/change_transmission_fluid_(af17)/

Comment: Is there is a drain plug, it will be on the bottom, but you haven’t shown any photos of the bottom of the transmission.

Comment: I have added a photo from the bottom and I also changed my question to be more specifit that I'm not asking for a drain plug, but I'm asking for  overflow plug, (it is also called "level plug" or "level check hole" or "fluid checking bolt").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about a “level plug”, but the transmission looks to me like it has a dip stick for checking the fluid level (The pipe with the paper label attached to it).

From my experience, auto transmissions that have a dip stick installed have been designed for fluid to be added down the dip stick tube and the level then checked with the dip stick.

Also from my experience, auto transmissions that don’t have a dip stick there has been a filler/level plug on the side of the transmission sump.

The photo you have added looks like there is a drain plug on the bottom.   If not, the old fluid could be ‘vacuumed’ out from the dipstick tube.

Comment: Yes, the Drain Plug on the bottom is working perfectly. And yes, there is a dip stick to measure the level. I just thought there would be a level plug on the side of the transmission sump. But I could not find one. Thank you for confirming that I should not continue looking for it

Comment: Please advice me on how can I improve my question so you would agree to vote it up. Please

Comment: Originally it wasn't very clear at all what you were asking.  As you have made edits it has become clearer.  Maybe if you had said that you knew there was a drain plug and that there was a dip stick, but you didn't know how to add transmission fluid and that you though there should be a plug for adding fluid, it would have been more obvious.